# How to Stop Redirect Loop?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 bits of code that I need help with!

Here is the first, which im trying to redirect the visitors that have no referrer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://sitetoredirectto.com [R,L]
```

and also visitors that type in my url directly (unless its my ip):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^28\.473\.38\.251
RewriteRule .* http://sitetoredirectto.com [R,L]
```

I want to get both of these into the same htaccess file so what do I have to change to get them both to allow only my IP while keeping the functionality they have plus stopping the redirect loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !sitetoredirectto\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^28\.473\.38\.251
RewriteRule .+ http://sitetoredirectto.com/? [R,L]
```